# create two dimensional array and loop through it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Objectives:

1. Create Two dimension array in javascript/jquery
2. Push data into it
3. Loop through each key,value pair
4. Call function in loop

Code:

```
    var IDs = [];
    /* Find Input elements and push its ID & Value into an array */
    $('#divDynamicFields').find("input").each(function () { 
       IDs.push(this.id, $(this).val()); 
   }); 
    console.log(IDs); /* Now it prints string seprated by ',' */

   /* Loop Through Each element in 2D array */
   $.each(IDs, function(key, value) { 
     $.each(key, function(innerKey, innerValue){
        CallFunction(id,val); 
        /* Will This Work ? */
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't see 2 dimensions in that 1 dimensional array. So I guess the answer is nope, that won't work.

Comment: @Spokey i want to create 2d array that holds `id,value` as pair

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wyoe27w/).

Comment: @Regent Post it as answer :)

Comment: @Shaggy ok, as it looks good for you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole idea is to push to array not two elements, but an array, which consists of two elements:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wyoe27w/).

```
var IDs = [];
$('#divDynamicFields input').each(function()
{ 
    IDs.push([this.id, $(this).val()]); 
});

for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++)
{
    CallFunction(IDs[i][0], IDs[i][1]);
}

function CallFunction(id, value)
{
    console.log("ID: " + id + ", value: " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use object
for insertion

```
var IDs = {};
$('#divDynamicFields').find("input").each(function () {     
   IDs[this.id]= $(this).val(); 
});
```

And similarly loop

```
$.each(IDs , function (index, value) {
    alert( index + ' : ' + value );
});
```

Comment: What is `news` and `obj`? `obj.[this.id]` - it should be `obj[this.id]`, shouldn't it? `$('#divDynamicFields').find("input")` will look a little better with `$('#divDynamicFields input')`.

Comment: @Regent , its typo error bro , logic is important.Thanks corrcted answer.DOWNVOTER care to comment?  Answer is correct?

Comment: A human being can understand the typo , `obj.[this.id]` to => `IDs.[this.id]`   Is this difficult ?

Comment: Is it difficult to correct all typos and mistakes in the answer? Answer should be answer, not "find and fix all mistakes and typos in it". I do not downvote answers, because I always hope that people will correct them. And downvoting answer as vengeance is very strange, don't you think so? And once more: it has to be `IDs[this.id]`, not `IDs.[this.id]`.

Comment: Ok you can do +1 if answer is correct . Now its correct ,and good for future users.

Comment: I post many my answers as question comments, so I don't have a lot of reputation to afford to myself any downvotes for other answers. So I always point to errors as answer comments. And yes, your answer is finally correct one, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems..

The first one is that you have to add the input as an array

```
       IDs.push([this.id, $(this).val()]);
```

The second one is that you want to call the ids you just added together, you don't want to do a double loop.

```
$.each(IDs, function(key, value) { 
      CallFunction(value[0],value[1]);
});
```

This is an example:

```
var IDs = [];
/* Find Input elements and push its ID & Value into an array */
$('#divDynamicFields').find("input").each(function () { 
   IDs.push([this.id, $(this).val()]); 
 }); 
console.log(IDs); /* Now it prints string seprated by ',' */

 /* Loop Through Each element in 2D array */
$.each(IDs, function(key, value) { 
       CallFunction(value[0],value[1]);
});

function CallFunction(id,val) {
   console.log(id+","+val);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hze3fp9e/)

Answer (score 0):

Your push syntax and iteration is wrong. You should do something like:

```js
var IDs = [];

IDs.push([1, 2]);
IDs.push([2, 3]);

/* Loop Through Each element in 2D array */
$.each(IDs, function(key, value) {
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**create two dimensional array**

```
MultiArray = new Array(5)

MultiArray [0] = new Array(2)

MultiArray [0][0] = "Tom"

MultiArray [0][1] = "scientist"

MultiArray [1] = new Array(2)

MultiArray [1][0] = "Beryl"

MultiArray [1][1] = "engineer"
```

https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/Array2D.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to create a dimensional array in jquery by using

```
var IDs = [];
 $('#divDynamicFields').find("input").each(function () { 
     IDs.push({
        id: $(this).val()           
     });
});

console.log(IDs);
```

This will allow you to send your all data whatever you want to pass in array by ajax.