# set jquery multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm getting attribute values. I need to set into multidimensional array but it's showing error. where im getting wrong ?

```
var myArray = [];
amount=10;
x=1
$(id).closest('td').nextAll().find('input').each(function (n) {

        myArray[x]['id'] = $(this).attr('data-id');
        myArray[x]['year'] = $(this).attr('data-year');
        myArray[x]['month'] = $(this).attr('data-month');
        myArray[x]['amount'] = amount;

        x++;
});
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create two dimensional array and loop through it in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140640/create-two-dimensional-array-and-loop-through-it-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing this line

```
myArray[x] = {};
```

before this line

```
myArray[x]['id'] = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

since you need to initialize this **object** first before setting properties to it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays need to be declared first to add items. For example

```
var d = [];
var value = 2;
d[0]["key"] = value;
```

won't work because `d[0]` is not an array yet. But:

```
var d = [];
var value = 2;
d[0]= [];
d[0]["key"] = value;
```

will work, because `d[0]` is ready to accept keys.

In your case;

```
>>> myArray[x] = [];
myArray[x]['id'] = $(this).attr('data-id');
myArray[x]['year'] = $(this).attr('data-year');
myArray[x]['month'] = $(this).attr('data-month');
myArray[x]['amount'] = amount;
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

Even though, you have initialized the array as an empty array, you should initialize the values at a paritcular location. when you dont specify, myArray[x] is undefined. So, you need to explicitly assign an empty object , so as to update keys using myArray[x]["key"]

```js
var myArray = [];
amount = 10;
x = 1
$(id).closest('td').nextAll().find('input').each(function(n) {
  //Need to initialize with an object a location x;
  myArray[x] = {};
  myArray[x]['id'] = $(this).attr('data-id');
  myArray[x]['year'] = $(this).attr('data-year');
  myArray[x]['month'] = $(this).attr('data-month');
  myArray[x]['amount'] = amount;

  x++;
});
console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```